# comment lines having contain text "test" using Python

Tags: python-2.7

i have a file. I want to comment with hash (#) those lines having text is "test".

a.txt:

```
this is test
test is this
this test is good
this good
```

so output should be...

```
#this is test
#test is this
#this test is good
this good
```

i tried regular expression to do but not working perfectly.

```
def convert_string():
  import re
  fh=open("tt.txt","rb")
  lines=fh.readlines()
  for line in lines:
     line= re.sub(r'^(test)',r'#\1',line)
     print line

  fh.close()
```

please help

Comment: Please check the sample output that you've posted. It doesn't seem consistent with your description. Also, I fixed formatting

Comment: [My answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17931054/198633) solves this problem correctly

Answer (score 1):

Regex is overkill for this. If you want to check if a substring exists in a larger string, just use `in`:

```
def comment_out(infilepath, outfilepath):
  with open(infilepath) as infile, open(outfilepath, 'w') as outfile:
    for line in infile:
      if 'test' not in line:
        outfile.write(line)
      else:
        outfile.write("#" + line)
```

If you want one-liners:

```
def comment_out(infilepath, outfilepath):
  with open(infilepath) as infile, open(outfilepath, 'w') as outfile:
    for line in infile:
        outfile.write(line if 'test' not in line else "#"+line)
```

If you want to overwrite the original file (this has linear space complexity):

```
def comment_out(infilepath):
  with open(infilepath) as infile:
    lines = list(infile)
  with open(infilepath, 'w') as outfile:
    outfile.write(''.join(line if 'test' not in line else "#"+line for line in lines))
```

Comment: actually 2 things i wanted to share. 1.) I wanted to use re.sub expression to reduce line of code because Perl has great feature to do in one line of code. 2.)Want to write in same file.

Comment: It's not a good idea to modify something as you're iterating over it. I'm updating my answer with two new methods that are in sync with your requirements

Comment: In Perl : $line =~ s/(?=.*\btest\b)/#/; is enough to change but same looking in Python.

Comment: There's no in-place regex replacer in python that I'm aware of. You might have to seek the file and overwrite. It goes without saying of course, that this is not a very safe option and can get very hacky

Comment: Thanks for reply but that all methods are in my mind. I was looking for re. for the same.